# Sequelize.js includes returning incorrect data

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm making a sample donations app and I want to get all of the donations a user has made, as well as the Causes that donation is connected too.

```js
exports.getUserDonations = (req, res) => {
  // Get Donations made by the user by userID
  Donation.findAll({
    where: {
      userID: req.params.id,
    },
    attributes: ['amount', 'updatedAt', 'causeID'],
    include: [{
      model: Cause,
      as: 'Causes',
    }]
  })
    .then(donations => {
      if (donations) {
        res.status(200).json(donations);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ error: "No Donations found" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error: ", err)
      res.status(500).json(err);
    });
}
```

For some reason I get this kind of result. As you can see the "causeID"(12) and the "Cause.id"(17) fields do not match. My thought is that the where statement above might be overriding something.

```js
    {
        "amount": 82,
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-02T17:04:30.847Z",
        "causeID": 12,
        "Causes": {
            "id": 17,
            "userID": 1,
            "orgID": null,
            "name": "Croation Trip",
            "type": "Trip",
            "amount": 3000,
            "description": "Just taking a trip",
            "purpose": "Food, sun, and fun",
            "createdAt": "2018-09-20T21:56:37.330Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-09-20T21:56:37.330Z"
        }
    },

// Most fo the time the cause comes back as null
{
    "amount": 10,
    "updatedAt": "2018-11-27T01:35:06.061Z",
    "causeID": 13,
    "Causes": null
},
```

Here are my associations for each of those

```js
   // Cause association
   Cause.associate = function(models) {
    Cause.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "Users",
      foreignKey: "id"
    })
    
    Cause.hasMany(models.Donation, {
      as: "Donations",
      foreignKey: "causeID"
    })
    
  };
  
  
  // Donation associations
  Donation.associate = function(models) {
    Donation.belongsTo(models.Cause, {
      as: "Causes",
      foreignKey: "id"
    })
    
    Donation.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "Users",
      foreignKey: "id"
    })
    
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mismatching some keys. I think your example is joining Donation.Id to Cause.Id - you should confirm by looking at the generated SQL.  Here's how to associate keys with different names:

```
Donation.belongsTo(models.Cause, {
      as: "Causes",
      {foreignKey: "id", sourceKey: "causeId"}
    })
```

Or test with more Donation attributes:

```
attributes: ['id', 'userId', 'amount', 'updatedAt', 'causeID'],
```

Does the donation id match the cause id?